# regex to filter a colon-separated list

Tags: regex

I use Word List Updater 2.7 for Windows and I need a regex to filter the following type of list.

This is the list of hashes:

```
Administrator:500:90lpA5CghgfF29A2D3A5A251441B67ju:2C3D3AF3B94337C248DE0C5A75AEAE1F:Built-in account for administering the computer/domain::

Guest:501:00000000000000000000000000000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:Built-in account for guest access to the computer/domain::

user:1002:00000000000000000000000000000000:F814ABE8BC04A52B0F4B503E2C80E037:::

paulenia1:1003:00000000000000000000000000000000:69C3A5C191AF29A2D3A5A251441B4E63:::
```

So first I need to leech only this part of each line:

```
2C3D3AF3B94337C248DE0C5A75AEAE1F
F814ABE8BC04A52B0F4B503E2C80E037
69C3A5C191AF29A2D3A5A251441B4E63
```

and then

```
administrator:2C3D3AF3B94337C248DE0C5A75AEAE1F
user:F814ABE8BC04A52B0F4B503E2C80E037
paulenia1:69C3A5C191AF29A2D3A5A251441B4E63
```

Comment: What doesn't work in the approach you tried?

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you can use this one:

#### `/^([A-z0-9]+):\d+:(?:0+:)*([A-z0-9]+):/gm`

- For each line,
- it captures a string of characters and digits at the beginning,
- followed by a colon,
- followed by some digits,
- followed by one (or more) optional group of zeroes with a trailing colon,
- followed by a captured group of characters and digits,
- followed by a colon.

See it in action: https://regex101.com/r/gU0oJ6/1

Granted, it also captures the zero-hash of the “Guest” user, but you probably still need it for comparison, or you simply drop it while you process the captured strings.

You asked for a regex, but as suggested in a comment, you can also simply split the strings at the colon. Here’s a JavaScript implementation of that:

```js
var arr = [
    'Administrator:500:90lpA5CghgfF29A2D3A5A251441B67ju:2C3D3AF3B94337C248DE0C5A75AEAE1F:…',
    'Guest:501:00000000000000000000000000000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:…',
    'user:1002:00000000000000000000000000000000:F814ABE8BC04A52B0F4B503E2C80E037:…',
    'paulenia1:1003:00000000000000000000000000000000:69C3A5C191AF29A2D3A5A251441B4E63:…'
];
arr.forEach(function(str){
    var split = str.split(':');
    if(split.length >= 4 && !/0{32}/.test(split[3]))
        document.writeln(split[0] + ':' + split[3] + '<br>');
});
```

```css
body{font-family:sans-serif;font-weight:bold;font-size:large;color:#0087DE;text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #777;}
```

Comment: @MunteanCosminManim: It worked [before](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32023109/revisions), but I added an runnable snippet. It outputs name and hash, just like you wanted.

Comment: i use that updater tool for windows...and i need the code for this tool, a regex code...not something else....so i take this code:

Comment: and not working : /^([A-z0-9]+):\d+:(?:0+:)*([A-z0-9]+):/gm

Comment: @MunteanCosminManim: Does it work for you in the above snippet or in [the simulator](https://regex101.com/r/gU0oJ6/1)?